# Why does grep return lines in the middle of the string when I expect it to be anchored at the beginning?

Tags: grep, bsd

I'm trying to extract the first word of the line when the line starts with whitespace, so I write the following command. But grep also returns the second word when it shouldn't. The ^ is supposed to match the beginning of the line:

```
echo -e "    cat   foo\n    dog   bar\n" | grep -Eo '^ +[^ ]+'
```

Returns:

```
    cat
   foo
    dog
   bar
```

I expect it to return:

```
    cat
    dog
```

I'm running on MacOS 10.15.7.

Comment: I can't repro: https://ideone.com/0HrwJL

Comment: Do you actually have literal tabs between the first and the second word? That would explain it. Try `[^[:space:]]` instead of `[^ ]` to cover all whitespace variations.

Comment: On Linux it works, on MacOS it doesn't.

Comment: Those are regular spaces, no tabs.

Comment: I can confirm that it is broken on BSD grep

Comment: Here is a [BSD bug report of this behavior](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166842)

Comment: thanks for digging that up. I think this command shows it best: `echo abc | grep -o '^[a-c]' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As stated here in this report, this is actually a bug in BSD `grep`.](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166842)

As a *work around*, you can use these `awk` and `sed` command to get equivalent output

```sh
cat file
    cat   foo
    dog   bar

sed -E 's/(^[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/' file
    cat
    dog

awk 'match($0, /^[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+/){print substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)}' file
    cat
    dog
```

Answer (score -1):

it's easy something like this :

```
echo -e "    cat   foo\n    dog   bar\n" | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*' | grep -o '^[^ ]\+'
```

or use `awk` like this

```
echo -e "    cat   foo\n    dog   bar\n" | awk 'NF==2{print $1}'
```

or `sed` like this :

```
echo -e "    cat   foo\n    dog   bar\n" | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*' | sed 's/ .*//'
```

or use `cut` like this

```
echo -e "    cat   foo\n    dog   bar\n" | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*' | cut -d" " -f1
```

output :

```
cat
dog
```

Comment: This doesn't reveal why the OP's code didn't work as expected.

Comment: @tripleee The above methods can be used temporarily, right?

Comment: Sure, though several of them are pretty crazy. The Awk one would be pretty natural but I don't understand why you put `NF==2` as a condition; probably at least explain the unlerlying assumption. Anyway, it's not like it's hard to find functionally equivalent replacements for the OP's code.

Comment: @tripleee yes you are right, but about `awk`, because without it I had extra new line at the end of `dog` line, so I wanted to get rid of the new line 

Comment: `awk 'NF==2{print $1}'` will not check for leading spaces and it will print without leading spaces as well.

Comment: @anubhava thank you, yes I mean after `bar` as you see we have `\n` so `NF==2` will remove it.